# 短縮URLでPV数を計測したい

Tags: next.js

短縮URLのようなサービスを個人開発しています。他サイトにリダイレクトするページで、PV数を測定する方法に悩んでいます。

技術選定

- Next.jsのISRで短縮URLのページを生成
- DBはSupabaseかPlanetScaleを検討中
- サーバーはLambdaかCloudflare Workersを検討中

やりたいこと

- URLごとにいつ、どこから(国)、何回閲覧されたか計測したい
- 早くリダイレクトできるよう、軽い処理にしたい
- PV数が増えてもDBに負荷がかからないようにしたい

検討中の方法

1. Google Analytics
   PV数の多い人が短縮URLを作成した場合、月1,000万ヒットまでの制限を超える心配があります。またリダイレクトページでCookieの確認をせずに、必要ない情報まで取得することもあまりしたくないです
2. 自前実装
   DBにインクリメントで１つずつ増やしていきます。PV数が急激に増えた場合、Supabase, PlanetScaleが書き込みの負荷に耐えられるか心配です。
3. ログ解析
   例えばNext.jsをAWSのAmplifyにホスティングします。AmplifyではISRをS3 + Cloudfrontで実装するため、Cloudfrontにアクセスログが残ります。これを解析して「URLごとにいつ、どこから(国)、何回閲覧されたか」を計測できるでしょうか